# IOS Scrolling Site Fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, html

I would like to make a parallax scrollable site for IOS, does anyone have any idea how to 'freeze' the screen to allow the device to recognise/react to  a scroll within a div?

Basically need something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/9R4hZ/40/ to work on an Ipad without the viewport moving all over the shop when scrolling..

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for touchmove events on the viewport div, prevent the standard scrolling behavior, and spoof a keypress or scroll wheel event (by using jQuery's .trigger method, for example). That will allow you to keep your current scrolling functionality while adding the touch event.

To get the direction the 'scroll' is happening you can start with something like this:

```
var lastTouch;
var scrollDirection;
var viewPort = document.getElementById("view");

viewPort.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if (lastTouch < event.targetTouches[0].pageY) {
        console.log("dragging down");
        scrollDirection = "up";
        //trigger up arrow keypress?

    }
    else if (lastTouch > event.targetTouches[0].pageY) {
        console.log("dragging up");
        scrollDirection = "down";
        //trigger down arrow keypress?          
    }

    lastTouch = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
});
```

You'll likely have to make some adjustments to how often you fire your scrolling event trigger, as the touchmove events may come too quickly.